# Error in xCore file in Eclipse 4.3(Kepler)

Tags: eclipse

I have just installed eclipse 4.3(Kepler) and when i open my xcore file it gives me some error:

> Couldn't resolve reference to XAnnotationDirective 'GenModel'
>   Couldn't resolve reference to XAnnotationDirective 'ExtendedMetaData'.

what could be the reason? any help will be appreciated.

Regards
Sharif

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused mainly due to incompatible dependencies and version mismatches. The following setting should fix your problem:

Firstly try doing a clean build. Generally that would solve your problem. But if it doesn't try the following:

`emf-xcore-SDK-VERSION` and the following dependencies:

Require-Bundle:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime,
org.eclipse.emf.ecore;visibility:=reexport,
org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib;visibility:=reexport,
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.lib
```

in the JAR's manifest file and rebuild.

**EDIT:** Turns out that the official documentation of `xcore` states to use either Eclipse 4.2 or 3.8. Also the first version of Xcore will be part of the Juno release train and is currently available in the Juno p2 repository. Maybe the subsequent versions will add Kepler build as well. You probably need to downgrade the Eclipse to 4.2 to make `xcore` work.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. i have tried to add xcore.lib in the manifest file but it give me error:   Bundle 'org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.lib' cannot be resolved

Comment: What about  `xtext`...? Does your xtext version match that of your xcore.. ?

Comment: my xcore sdk is 1.2.0 and xtext sdk 2.4.3

Comment: but what is the reasone for : Bundle 'org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.lib' cannot be resolved

Comment: It's because you probably might not have `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` in your project.

Comment: but if i add org.eclipse.emf.ecore in my manifest file, still i got the same error.  Bundle 'org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xcore.lib' cannot be resolved

Comment: The only possible explanation I can come up with now is that the official documentation states to use either Eclipse 3.8 or 4.2. Probably an issue with the 4.3. I use Juno and the above steps solved my problem. Refer: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xcore#Getting_Started.